# Using a union but getting an error that the prop does not exists

Tags: typescript, union-types

I've got a variable which type is a union:

```
const waypoint: Waypoint;
```

The `Waypoint` type is a union of 2 types:

```
type Waypoint = UtmNZ | GeoNZ;

export interface GeoNZ {
  latitude: number;
  longtitude: number;
}

export interface UtmNZ {
  latitude: number;
  longtitude: number;
  zone: number;
}
```

Later on I declared a function that accepts this union and needs to decide at runtime whether the argument's type is UtmNZ or a GeoNZ and use one of the functions `renderUTM()` or `renderGeo()` accordingly.

Here is the function that needs to figure the `Waypoint` actual type at runtime:

```
renderWaypoint(waypoint: Waypoint): string {
    if(!waypoint?.latitude || !waypoint?.longtitude) return 'נ.צ. לא תקין';
    if ('zone' in this.waypoint)
        return renderUTM(waypoint);
    else
        return renderGeo(waypoint);
}
```

And here is the specific render function signatures:

```
function renderGeo(waypoint: GeoNZ): string
function renderUTM(waypoint: UtmNZ): string
```

I get an **error** that says `waypoint` is missing a prop which should exist thank to the union.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

> A type guard is some expression that performs a runtime check that guarantees the type in some scope.

To define a type guard, we simply need to define a function whose return type is a type predicate. `waypoint is UtmNZ` is our type predicate in this example. A predicate takes the form `parameterName is Type`, where `parameterName` must be the name of a parameter from the current function signature.

E.g.

```
type Waypoint = UtmNZ | GeoNZ;

export interface GeoNZ {
  latitude: number;
  longtitude: number;
}

export interface UtmNZ {
  latitude: number;
  longtitude: number;
  zone: number;
}

class Example {
  waypoint = {
    zone: 1,
  };
  renderWaypoint(waypoint: Waypoint): string {
    if (!waypoint.latitude || !waypoint.longtitude) return 'נ.צ. לא תקין';
    if (isUTM(waypoint)) return renderUTM(waypoint);
    else return renderGeo(waypoint);
  }
}

function isUTM(waypoint: Waypoint): waypoint is UtmNZ {
  return 'zone' in waypoint;
}

function renderGeo(waypoint: GeoNZ): string {
  return 'geo';
}
function renderUTM(waypoint: UtmNZ): string {
  return 'utm';
}

const utm: Waypoint = { zone: 123, latitude: 123, longtitude: 321 };

const exmaple = new Example();
console.log(exmaple.renderWaypoint(utm)); // output: utm
```